# how to horizontally center align body wrapper?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I would like to know if there's a better way to do a 1600px wide wrapper body to horizontally center align to all screen sizes.

I'm using these:

`if($(window).width() > 1400) {
        $('body').scrollLeft(80);
    }
    if($(window).width() > 1281 && $(window).width() <= 1400){
        $('body').scrollLeft(140);
    }
    if ($(window).width() < 1280){
        $('body').scrollLeft(195);
    }
    if ($(window).width() < 1024){
        $('body').scrollLeft(300);
    }`

Comment: please give a demo link

Comment: @JentiDabhi here's a sample link: http://kat.isltest.net/col/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several trial and error, I have came up with my own answer. It's a little bit of a hard-coded thing, but so far, this solves my problem in aligning wide divs responsively on any screen sizes.

```
$(window).on('resize', function() {
if ($(window).width() <= 1600) {
    $(document).scrollLeft(0);
}
if ($(window).width() <= 1536) {
    $(document).scrollLeft(40);
}
if ($(window).width() <= 1440) {
    $(document).scrollLeft(110);
}
if ($(window).width() <= 1360) {
    $(document).scrollLeft(130);
}
if ($(window).width() <= 1280) {
    $(document).scrollLeft(170);
}
if ($(window).width() <= 1152) {
    $(document).scrollLeft(235);
}
if ($(window).width() <= 1024) {
    $(document).scrollLeft(300);
}
if ($(window).width() <= 800){
    $(document).scrollLeft(400);
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure why you need Javascript for this.  You can just use a centering content div; see the attached code snippet (set at 200px wide, but the result is the same).

```css
.content {
  width: 200px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head><title>Body Centering</title></head>
  <body>
    <div class="content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aliquam posuere nibh a elit egestas fermentum. Nunc eu velit venenatis, blandit nulla a, gravida justo. Sed accumsan arcu in mi dapibus pretium. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nulla fermentum, augue eget aliquam pharetra, turpis diam ornare neque, a interdum ipsum ligula aliquam nunc. Maecenas eu eleifend libero.</p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what if the content class is 1600px wide? it stays on the left as a default, that's why I'm trying these javascripts.

Comment: The margin-left: auto and margin-right: auto will center the content div in whatever the body width is.  If the body width is smaller than the content div, then yes, it will be left aligned.

You can force a particular width by attaching a width (or min-width) to the body, although that wouldn't be very responsive.

Comment: Or are you saying you want the content width to be potentially *wider* than the body width and force-centered (that is, scrolled offscreen to the left)?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create a responsive site, I would suggest using @media queries to do so. In your css try using something like this:

```
body {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1400px) {
.wrapper {
    width: 1600px;
}
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
.wrapper {
    width: 1280px;
}
}
@media screen and (max-width: 1280px) {
.wrapper {
    width: 1280px;
}
}
```

Of course I would change the width size of the wrapper depending on what size you would like it to be, but this should make your site responsive to screen size. The other option would be to make the style of the wrapper `.wrapper { width: 100%; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;`

Let me know if I misunderstood your question or if this helped.

Comment: I would like wrapper be fixed as 1600px and centered to any screen sizes. here's my work: http://kat.isltest.net/column/

Comment: @kgam Your current settings do have the content within the wrapper centered when set to 1600px; I see that you have overflow set to hidden in your source code. are you suggesting that you would like the red and green areas to be out of view and the Gray area to be centered? Or did you want the viewport to be centered on the page so that you can scroll to the left and right on the initial page load?

Comment: yes the viewport to be centered and I can scroll the left and right panels. the result should be the wrapper should be centered so that the gray area is centered and the red and green panels are just initially opened, and when you scroll left or right, you can also see the red and green panels.